# Transparent window in Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

How can I create a transparent window in Qt for Linux. I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
myWidget::myWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint) {
   setWindowOpacity(0.4);
}
```

Comment: I imagine you already tried windowOpacity?

Comment: A transparent window is working fine for me. I was just forgetting about the opacity. This question itself reminded me to use it. Now everything is working just fine! Thanks! +1 for this. : )

Answer (score 3):

> "Note that under X11 you need to have
> a composite manager running, and the
> X11 specific _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY
> atom needs to be supported by the
> window manager you are using."

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop

What window manager are you using?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager#List_of_compositing_window_managers

Does your server support the "Composite extension"?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_(graphics)

Does your card support it?

Comment: I use gnome as window manager. On MS Windows code from the first post is working properly

Comment: Yes, on windows XP and above (with proper video card ofcourse), because THEY HAVE SIMPLE composite manager. You must have composite manager in your X11 server to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [QGraphicsOpacityEffect](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html) and [QWidget::setGraphicsEffect](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#setGraphicsEffect)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but on windows, not sure if it will help in Linux
Instead of Qt::FramelessWindowHint use Qt::SplashScreen. I can have a frameless and transparent window on top of my other widgets.